# Calculated column or measure using IF statement

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Objective:**

I would like to make a measure and a calculated column (for the sake of knowing how to write both) using an IF statement but can't get it to work

**Query:**

```
Column = 
IF(
    Refund[orderTotalPrice]=Refund[amount] && Refund[status] = 'refund' , 
    Refund[amount] - Refund[total_tax]- Refund[shipping_price],
    Refund[amount]
    )
```

> the expression refers to multiple columns multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value

Comment: Are you getting that error using it for a calculated column, as a measure, or both?

Comment: both  measure and cal. column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an if statement in a **calculated column** you can **only have one comparison statement**. If you want 2, like in your example, you need to use the AND function. Also make sure you use " instead of ' for string comparison.

I tested this calculated column and this worked for me:

```
Column = if(
AND(Refund[orderPriceTotal]=Refund[amount],Refund[status]="Refund"),
Refund[amount] - Refund[total_tax] - Refund[shipping price],
Refund[amount]
)
```

In your case, I do not think there is an easy solution to solve this in a measure. Why would you want to build it as a measure?

Comment: it works as a column, but better for me to use it as a measure to optimize my report